# how do you convert an array from one data type to another in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I'm using vb.net 2008 edition and i was wondering if there a way to convert an array type to another array type.  For instance say i dim an array as string and then want to convert the array to the integer data type for sorting, how would i go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
intArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, Function(s) Int32.Parse(s))
```

Comment: what is intArray? should i dim a new array called intArray?

Comment: If you want to.  What did you want to do with the array of integers?

Comment: well actually i started out with a string array and want to convert it to a integer array.  and even though i put that exact line of code in my program it did nothing and stayed a string array. heres what i tried

       Array.ConvertAll(cardNumber, Function(s) Int32.Parse(s))

where cardNumber is just a 5 spot string array.

Comment: You need to declare a new variable of type `Int32()` and assign the return value to it.

Comment: thank for clearing that up! works like a charm :)  i'm very grateful . . .